# Ng-model does not update HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

On ng-click I change model but html is same...

html

```
<p>Rezervisanih:<span>{{seatsInfo}}</span></p>
<div ng-click="change()">change</div>
```

js

```
$scope.seatsInfo = 20;

$scope.change = function(){
    $scope.seatsInfo = 30;
    console.log($scope.seatsInfo);    
}
```

Comment: That code should work - could you put up your whole controller?

Comment: I am sure there is more than meets the eye. Can you paste more information? Are the `p` and `div` tags really sibling DOM nodes?

Comment: application is on this link [link](http://snh.rs/dom)

Comment: to be more specific [link](http://snh.rs/dom/#/event) 
when you click on seat the left info need to be change

Comment: Where is the `ng-click` part in the application? I found the `span` text but could not find the `change()` part.

Comment: in template... http://snh.rs/dom/templates/event.html

Comment: Are you speaking of the `update()` method? Your question says `change()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at the app that you posted, I see that the update() call is actually within an ng-repeat scope. So you will be impacting a different scope level.

Make use of the [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) to ensure that you are setting the value on the correct scope level.

Comment: `ng-repeat` does create a new scope. However, it will inherit the properties of the parent scope.